# Number is not added at back of existing array

Tags: java, arrays

Learning about Arrays. I am not able to figure out why a new number is not added to the back of my existing array. I read in two textfiles in file_1.txt are the numbers '1 2 3' and in file_2.txt is the number '91'. Basically without the method of `Void addBack()` the program does what I expect, however by adding the method it seems not make a new Array. Even when I go over the `elements[i] = elements[i-1]` it won't print it as a whole. I am expecting to print for the first part
`The numbers are: 1 2 3`  and the second part `The numbers are: 1 2 3 91`.

```
public class ExampleLecture {
    
    IntRow readIntRow(Scanner input) {
        IntRow result = new IntRow();
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            result.add(input.nextInt());
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    IntRow setBack(Scanner input) {
        IntRow result = new IntRow();
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            result.addBack(input.nextInt());
            System.out.println("here");
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    void print(IntRow row) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.numberOfElements; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d ", row.elements[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
        
    void start() {
        
        Scanner in = UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();
        Scanner in2 =UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();
        IntRow row = readIntRow(in);
        IntRow row2 = setBack(in2);
        
        
        System.out.printf("the numbers are: ");
        print (row);
        System.out.printf("the new numbers are: ");
        print (row2);


        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExampleLecture().start();
    }

}
```

```
    package examplelecture;

class IntRow {
    
    static final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS = 250;
    
    int[] elements;
    int numberOfElements;
    
    IntRow() {
        elements = new int[MAX_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS];
        numberOfElements = 0;
    }
    
    void add(int number) {
        elements[numberOfElements] = number;
        numberOfElements += 1;
    }
    
    void addBack(int number) {
        for (int i = numberOfElements; i>0; i--) {
            elements[i] = elements[i-1];
            elements[i] = number;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should addBack() do? The name of the method and your code is misleading. Should it add a number at the beginning of the array (i.e. index 0)?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 successive assignments which write to the same position:

```
elements[i] = elements[i-1];
elements[i] = number;
```

The value is alway overwritten with number, so the first statement has no effect.

Also in your `addBack` method your for cycle:

```
for (int i = numberOfElements; i>0; i--) {
```

What happens if numberOfElements is 0?

---

You call it `addBack` but it looks like a better name for the method is `addFirst`. Usually index 0 is considered the front, not the back.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly it is not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish. But you may have several problems.  The first is as follows:

```
    IntRow setBack(Scanner input) {
        IntRow result = new IntRow();
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            result.addBack(input.nextInt());
            System.out.println("here");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

`IntRow` has nothing in it since it is new.  So all you are doing is iterating over the new file which has just `91` in it.  Remember, result has no items. So it won't even iterate once in `addBack`.

So just do the following:

Change your `addBack` method to just add the numbers. Why use a loop to cascade down the elements since you are doing this within the same instance of IntRow?  Just add it on to the end using the `numberofElements` as the next index.

```
void addBack(int number) {
        elements[numberOfElements++] = number;        
}
```

If you want to copy the contents of one IntRow object to another you would need another method in the `IntRow` class.  Something like:

```
public void copy(IntRow r) {
    for (int i = 0; i < r.numerOfElements; i++) {
        elements[i] = r.elements[i];
    }
    numerOfElements = r.numberOfElements;
}
```

And keeping with good design it might be better to return numberOfElements in a method such as `public int size();`

Answer (score 0):

First off, both the `readIntRow()` and `setBack()` methods create new IntRow objects `row` and `row2`.  If you want the result to be appended to the first IntRow object created i.e. to `row`  , you should call:

```
        IntRow row = readIntRow(in);
        IntRow row2 = row.setBack(in2);
```

and `setBack()` needs to be modified to:

```
    IntRow setBack(Scanner input) {
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            this.add(input.nextInt());
            System.out.println("here");
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Note that in `setBack()`, if you are trying to append numbers to the end of the IntRow object, you should call `add()` instead of `addBack()` as above. If you are trying to add to the front, you should call `addBack()` [and it might be better to call it `addFront()` instead].

Also, in the implementation of `addBack()`, if you are trying to add to the front of the IntRow object, the `element[i] = number` operation should take place only once, after the loop. Otherwise all the values in indices <= numberOfElements would be overwritten with number.

```
    void addBack(int number) {
        for (int i = numberOfElements; i>0; i--) {
            elements[i] = elements[i-1];
        }
        elements[0] = number;
    }
```